# Browsers support module imports, how do I use it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to figure out why my script tags don't work in my html file, and I came across an article that says you can *import modules* into browsers via a script tag with a `module` type. Directly from this site: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
 // or
<script type="module">
  import { something } from './somewhere.js';
    // ...
</script>
```

So then I tried it and the imported module is recognized but getting this error `Can't find variable World` is it because my *example.js* file doesn't have it in its scope?  I don't understand the order in which they are "processed?" don't know the terminology sorry.

My attempt below

```
//HTML 
<body>
  <script type="module">
    import { World, Ball, Paddle, Brick, Hud} from "./brickbreakclasses.js"
  </script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
```

*example.js* file

```
 // commented this part out because it was imported in html file    
 // import { World, Ball, Paddle, Brick, Hud } from "./brickbreakclasses";
var canvas = new World(document.getElementById("canvas") );
var ball = new Ball(canvas)
var brick = new Brick(canvas)
var hud = new Hud(canvas)
var paddle = new Paddle(canvas)
```

I hope this makes sense but I really want to understand why I can't just require or import something in JS file and add it to html via script. I've been using webpack to bundle everything and putting that into my html.However I'm now making a npm package and I hear people don't like pre-bundled packages so I'm trying to find a way for a user to use my modules in html without having to install webpack or something like it.

Comment: Each module is evaluated in its own scope, not in global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables declared inside a `<script type="module">` are local to that module. Make `example.js` a module, import the classes from there, and you can use them:

HTML

```
<body>
  <script type="module" src="example.js"></script>
</body>
```

example.js

```
import { World, Ball, Paddle, Brick, Hud } from "./brickbreakclasses.js";
var canvas = new World(document.getElementById("canvas") );
var ball = new Ball(canvas);
var brick = new Brick(canvas);
var hud = new Hud(canvas);
var paddle = new Paddle(canvas);
```

Comment: oh wow thats weird I'm so used to not having to add the file extension to the path. normally in node I don't have to. I thought vanilla would be the same. its working now, thank you @AuxTaco

Comment: Node can make educated guesses about the actual filename; the browser can't. You could be importing from the output of a PHP script at `"https://static.example.com/ill_advised_dynamic_script?call_a_brick_a=brick"`.

Comment: My point is that the browser can't make the assumption that `"./brickbreakclasses"` actually means "make a request to `http://example.com/brickbreakclasses.js`".